# Баба — женщина и баба — часть молота

Tags: омонимы

Интересно, оба эти слова — омонимы и не имеют друг к другу никакого отношения или они как-то связаны?
Спасибо заранее.

Comment: А еще есть "ромовая баба"(кондитерское изделие),а еще - "каменная баба"(истуканы,предположительно скифского происхождения, в степях от Причерноморья до Забайкалья), а сколько значений этого слова мы просто не помним или не знаем, потому что, хоть они и встречаются в написанном виде, все они - просторечия, возникающие и исчезающие по воле случая,вследствие каких-то маловразумительных ассоциаций.

Answer (score 3):

Ромовые, каменные и снежнве - одного поля ягоды с бабой молотобойной.
Нечто большое, массивное, гиреподобное по форме.
А вот с женшиной - вернее всего омонимы. 
Баба, бабка - это очень древний корень, вряд ли его могли перенести на всякое-разное ромово-снежно-каменное.

Answer (score 3):

Ромовая  баба  первоначально  -  бабА.  В  разговорном  варианте  ударение  сместилось  на  более  привычное.  Следовательно  это  омонимы.  Тюркские  каменные  изваяния  без  бороды  были,  возможно, прозваны   "каменными  бабами"  по  этому  признаку.  Здесь  связь  с  словом  баба (  женщина )  проявляется.  Но  в  то  же  время  в  тюркских  языках  "баба" -  отец,  в  татарском  старик  "бабай".  Если  в  словосочетании  "каменная  баба"  используется  русифицированное  тюркское  слово,  то  тут  тоже  омонимы.  А  почему  копёр  или  трамбовка  называется  "бабой" - не  нашёл.

Comment: >Ромовая баба первоначально - бабА  
  
Упс! Подтвердить можете?
Буду признателен, не слышал такого объяснения.

Comment: Название  выпечки  пришло  из  турецкого  через  французский.  Читал  в  статье  типа:  почему  мы  так  говорим.  Ссылку  сходу  дать  не  могу  -  надо  искать.

Comment: Оказалось  несколько  не  так.  Но  согласно  этой  версии  автором  названия  был  король  польский  король  Станислав  Лещинский.  И  произвёл  он  название  кекса  от  имени  Али-бабА, с  ударением  на  втором  слоге.  Врочем  другие  версии  тоже  имеют  право  на  существование.  http://www.homebread-shop.ru/istoriya-vozniknoveniya-romovoy-babyi

Comment: Но  и  в  этом  случае - омоним.

Comment: ОК, спасибо.
Я думаю, это просто две **разные** "версии", обе никакой критики не выдерживают. 
По-французски было бы бабА, по-польски "бАба ромОва". Ну а турки не употребляли алкоголь даже в кулинарных целях. Тогдашние турки, разумеется.

Comment: Так  по французски и было  наверно,  это  же  язык  межнационального  общения  высшего  общества,  и  Станислав  Лещинский  на  нём  говорил,  и  арабские  сказки  читал  во  французском  переводе.  Хотя  сама  версия  больше  похожа  на  сказку.  Это,  да.  Турецкий  след  я  привёл  ошибочно.  Ошибка  памяти  произошла.

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще близкая форма слова:

Бабка (phalanx рrimа) — есть первый сустав или фаланг пальца жвачных животных (быка, овцы, козы и проч.). Эта кость служит для игры «в бабки», которая распространена между детьми простонародья по всей России, как в деревнях, так и в городах.

Comment: Да.  Но  для  бабки ( выпечки ) это  тоже,  скорее,  омоним.  А  вот  высокая,  пышная  и  сдобная  баба (выпечка,  но  не  "ромовая  баба" )  вполне  может  иметь  метафорическое  происхождение  т.к.  это  русское  ( славянское )  блюдо,  и  могло  указывать  на  женский  идеал.

Comment: баба, бабка - вообще весьма многозначное слово. И не всегда просматривается связь той же лошадиной бабки например с названием снопов, оставленных на поле во время жатьбы. 
А вот большинство упомянут здесь "баб" вполне пригодны для объединения по принципу формы, массивности.

Comment: Этимологию  бабки - надкопытной  кости - я  вообще  не  нашёл.

Answer (score 0):

По поводу ромовой бабы. 
Есть такая крестьянская еда - "хлебная бабка". Как тюря, только с меньшим количеством жидкости и "вылепленное" в виде куличика. Это я к тому, что название баба, бабка для кеска могло быть вполне русским. Вот рецепт - это да, заимствованный. В этом слабость версии, обычно кушанье заимствуется вместе названием, а другого названия для ром-бабы не сохранилось. Но бывает всякое...

Comment: Была  и  выпечка - баба.  Даль  отмечает.  Вот  она  сдобная  и  пышная.  И  бабка - баба  меньших  размеров.  Сами  пишете,  что  рецепт  заимствуется  с  названием,  что  же  мешает  несколько  переиначить  название  на  привычный  манер  в  среде,  где  на  французском  не  говорят. К  тому  выпечка  с  таким  названием  уже  есть.